# Memcache and Mysqli Prepared Statement Issue

Tags: php, mysqli, memcached

This has been driving me crazy, the issue is I cannot work out How i can get and set the cached data to be displayed within my view.

```
public function get_something($id, $account_name)
{
    $sql = "SELECT one,two,three FROM table WHERE id = ? and account_name = ? ";
    $key = md5("SELECT one,two,three FROM table WHERE id = $id and account_name = $account_name ");

    $get_result = $this->Core->Core->Memcache->get($key);

    if($get_result)
    {
      // How would I set the Data
    }
    else
    {
     $stmt = $this->Core->Database->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->bind_param("is", $id, $account_name);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->store_result();
     $stmt->bind_result($one, $two, $three);
     $stmt->fetch();
     //Below is how i set the data
     $this->Core->Template->set_data('one', $one);  
     //Set the Memcache
     $this->Core->Memcache->set($key, $stmt, TRUE, 20);
}
```

So my question is how can I get and set the data from a prepared statement fetch within memcache?

Comment: Why are you trying to save the prepared statement instead of the results? The latter should work.

Comment: Would this mean i set the $stmt->fetch(); to $results = $stmt->fetch(); then set the memcache set to $result not $stmt?

Comment: Because if I do what I just stated, this error occurs Notice: Memcache::get(): unable to unserialize data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memcache is a key/value storage system with both the key and the value needing to be serialized.  From the [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php) page:

> Remember that resource variables (i.e. file and connection descriptors) cannot be stored in the cache, because they cannot be adequately represented in serialized state.

It appears your sql statement is looking for three values in a single row.  I'm no expert on mysqli, but this is kind of what you want to do:

```
public function get_something($id, $account_name){
  $sql = "SELECT one,two,three FROM table WHERE id = ? and account_name = ? ";
  $key = md5("SELECT one,two,three FROM table WHERE id = $id and account_name = $account_name ");

  $get_result = $this->Core->Core->Memcache->get($key);

  if($get_result){
    return $get_result;//#1 just return it, the format is an array like what is being built below
  }
  else{
   $stmt = $this->Core->Database->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bind_param("is", $id, $account_name);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->store_result();
   $stmt->bind_result($one, $two, $three);
   $stmt->fetch();
   //Below is how i set the data
   $this->Core->Template->set_data('one', $one);//#2 I don't know what this line does or is for, presumably for something else besides memcache stuff, maybe it acts like return
   //Set the Memcache
   $array=array();//#3
   $array[]=$one;
   $array[]=$two;
   $array[]=$three;

   $this->Core->Memcache->set($key, $array, TRUE, 20);
   //this is a function, do you want to return your values somewhere?
 }
```

A few notes, #1 the answer to your question is simple, just return `$get_result`. It should be an array with three values. #2 I'm not familiar with this line, nor what it does.  Is this how your "return" the values to your controller?  If so, you'll want to mimick that line where I put the `return` inside the `if`  #3 This is your problem.  You can't save the `$stmt` variable in memcache, it's a mysqli object, not the data you want.  You need to build an array and then save that array.  And that should do it for you.

There are other nuances to do, you can loop on the returned values.  You should check for mysql not returning anything.  But this is the basic starting point to get this going.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comments landon, I ended up doing something very similar to your answer... What I will do is test and see what/if it is better than what I have... Then mark this as the answer. My other concern is if a separate function deletes or updates the variables in the above example, the how would I go about updating or deleting the variables stored in Memcache?

Comment: you have to make sure your update/delete function does a similar action to the memcache record.  you could safely delete it, and then count on this to fill it if you're ok with the one time hit of a mysql lookup.

Comment: for this reason, having a very organized key name structure is very important, you need to accurately be able to find the name of that particular key to wipe it when you edit it elsewhere